# Can't install Keras 1.1 on anaconda

Tags: keras, conda

Using Anaconda 2.2.0 I'm trying to install an older version of Keras, specifically 1.1.0.

So far I've just put in anaconda prompt `conda install keras=1.1.0` but I've been getting the following error.

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - keras=1.1.0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to install `keras 1` on Anaconda? Is it safe to use `pip install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no available candidates (for win64) in the default channels and also not in the `free` channel.

Is it "safe" to use `pip`?

You can find a [good blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment) from anaconda on the topic. The gist is: You can do it, but take care. For Anaconda, I would always suggest to not mess with the base env in any way. If you create a new env, install everything that you need besides `keras` and then `pip install keras=1.1` you should be fine. You can even do it using an environment.yml file like this (I added `six`, `theano` and `pyyaml` as they are dependencies of `keras`:

```
name: keras
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python
  - theano
  - six
  - pyyaml
  - pip
  - pip:
    - keras==1.1
```

Simply create the env and then use it by activating

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
conda activate keras
```